# Ekert protocol understanding - correlations/anti-correlations of measurements by Alice and Bob

Tags: qkd

I have question related to the Ekert Protocol. Attached is the link for Ekert's original paper titled "Quantum Cryptography based on Bell's Theorem".

https://cqi.inf.usi.ch/qic/91_Ekert.pdf

My question is: How is the equation (2) derived from equation (1)?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Please avoid posting scans of articles. Instead, quote the necessary parts and provide name of the article and a link.

Comment: It isnt. It's derived from the Born rule. The author is considering measuring a singlet with qubit observables parameterised by bloch vectors. This is then the expectation value.

Comment: Thanks. Think I found an answer here:  https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8473/probability-of-equal-outcomes-measuring-a-bell-state-in-the-directions-vecn
Probability of getting equal measurements is ½(1-n1.n2)
If n1 and n2 are the same direction, then the probability of getting equal measurements is 0.
Probability of getting unequal measurements = probability of measurement results being anti-correlated = 1
Correlation coefficient of measurements being anti-correlated = 1
Correlation coefficient of measurements being correlated = -1
Which is same as equation (2)